# Need a view to post to a different controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a search bar on my Home-Index page:

```
<p>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")  
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
```

I need to submit this string into my code controller and take the user to the Code-Index page using the code controller, rather than the home controller. It seems the parameter is not enough for it to pick it up:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: You should be able to just post the form to the controller you want to use...Could you add the rest of your form HTML?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap it in a form and specify the controller and the action you want to submit to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SomeOtherControllerName"))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")  
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: saw the mvc tag and was wondering where Mr.Dimitrov was :) +1